# sql query to show records created this month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write an sql query that must show me records that are only created last month..for example, if this month is June, I want the query to show me records of May.

This is my query but it is not working.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS stdtotal_today FROM `login`
WHERE `login_account_type` = 'STUDENT' 
AND `account_created_date` = CURDATE() - 30
```

Note that `login` is the table name and `account_created_date` is the column name of type date.

Comment: Not surprised, you are saying `account_created_date = {A specific DAY}`

Comment: How is your table set up? Do you have a month column? If so, you could add in "WHERE Month = "May"

Comment: Look up the `BETWEEN` syntax [here in the manual for example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 4):

Try This :

```
SELECT * FROM `login`
WHERE `login_account_type` = 'STUDENT'  AND YEAR(`account_created_date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(`account_created_date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS stdtotal_today FROM `login` WHERE account_created_date
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```